# How can a Java program get its own process ID?

Tags: java, pid

How do I get the id of my Java process?

I know there are several platform-dependent hacks, but I would prefer a more generic solution.

Comment: A link to a Linux question: [How do I find my PID in Java or JRuby on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138097/772981)

Comment: This is meant to be fixed in JDK9. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102

Comment: Way to [do it in Java SE10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959178/1592191)

Comment: Another way is to create a JNI library.

Answer (score 422, accepted):

There exists no platform-independent way that can be guaranteed to work in all jvm implementations.
`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` looks like the best (closest) solution, and typically includes the PID. It's short, and *probably* works in every implementation in wide use.

On linux+windows it returns a value like `"12345@hostname"` (`12345` being the process id). Beware though that [according to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getName%28%29), there are no guarantees about this value:

> Returns the name representing the running Java virtual machine. The
> returned name string can be any arbitrary string and a Java virtual
> machine implementation can choose to embed platform-specific useful
> information in the returned name string. Each running virtual machine
> could have a different name.

**In Java 9** the new [process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) can be used:

```
long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
```

Comment: This solution is really fragile. See an answer about Hyperic Sigar below.

Comment: that pid is good to write on a lock file as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9020391/1422630

Comment: @MichaelKlishin in what regard is that fragile?

Answer (score 132):

You could use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). Unfortunately there is no common JNA API to get the current process ID yet, but each platform is pretty simple:

### Windows

Make sure you have `jna-platform.jar` then:

```
int pid = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();
```

### Unix

Declare:

```
private interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);   
    int getpid ();
}
```

Then:

```
int pid = CLibrary.INSTANCE.getpid();
```

---

## Java 9

Under Java 9 the new [process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) can be used to get the current process ID. First you grab a handle to the current process, then query the PID:

```
long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
```

Comment: +1 But I'm afraid that in a security constrained environment it should not work (tomcat, WebLogic, etc.).

Comment: The `getpid()` solution also works for OS X, with a JNA call to the "System" library.

Comment: However, I get `error: cannot find symbol` for jdk9

Answer (score 63):

Here's a backdoor method which *might* not work with all VMs but should work on both linux and windows ([original example here](http://boxysystems.com/index.php/java-tip-find-process-id-of-running-java-process/)):

```
java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = 
    java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
jvm.setAccessible(true);
sun.management.VMManagement mgmt =  
    (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method =  
    mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
pid_method.setAccessible(true);

int pid = (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
```

Comment: very nice, just verified that it works both on the JRockit as well as the Hotspot JVMs.

Comment: Nice workaround. I'm going to assume there is a good reason why this method (and others in the class) aren't public and easily accessible, and I'm curious to know what it is.

Comment: Oracle Java team have announced that they intend to hide all non-java packages (i.e. sun.*) I believe starting with Java 10 (scheduled for 2018 - maybe Java 9).  If you have a similar implementation as the one above, you may want to figure out an alternative so that your code don't break.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either as the sun.* packages are probably removed or inaccessible (VMManagement cannot be resolved to a type).

Comment: Due to the way reflection works, access to sun.management.* is not needed. Just perform the `getDeclaredMethod` on the Object returned by `jvm.get(runtime)`.

Answer (score 36):

Try [Sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) . very extensive APIs.  Apache 2 license.

```java
private Sigar sigar;

public synchronized Sigar getSigar() {
    if (sigar == null) {
        sigar = new Sigar();
    }
    return sigar;
}

public synchronized void forceRelease() {
    if (sigar != null) {
        sigar.close();
        sigar = null;
    }
}

public long getPid() {
    return getSigar().getPid();
}
```

Comment: You'd have a lot more upvotes if you explained *how* to use SIGAR for this

Comment: Link is broken.  You give an example of how to use this, but is there a maven dependency for it?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperic/sigar seems to be a usable location; this also shows that it's native code with Java bindings, which may make it less of a solution for many contexts.

Answer (score 30):

The following method tries to extract the PID from `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory`:

```
private static String getProcessId(final String fallback) {
    // Note: may fail in some JVM implementations
    // therefore fallback has to be provided

    // something like '<pid>@<hostname>', at least in SUN / Oracle JVMs
    final String jvmName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    final int index = jvmName.indexOf('@');

    if (index < 1) {
        // part before '@' empty (index = 0) / '@' not found (index = -1)
        return fallback;
    }

    try {
        return Long.toString(Long.parseLong(jvmName.substring(0, index)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return fallback;
}
```

Just call `getProcessId("<PID>")`, for instance.

Comment: VisualVM uses similar code to get self PID, check com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.jvm.Jvm#ApplicationSupport#createCurrentApplication(). They are the experts, so it looks like dependable, cross platform solution.

Comment: @Espinosa VisualVM only supportes running on a OpenJDK/Oracle/GraalVM JVM (as of 2020).  This mean they can make assumptions accordingly.  If you do the same, you become vendor dependent and your code may break if running on for instance J9.

Answer (score 25):

For older JVM, in linux...

```
private static String getPid() throws IOException {
    byte[] bo = new byte[256];
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/proc/self/stat");
    is.read(bo);
    for (int i = 0; i < bo.length; i++) {
        if ((bo[i] < '0') || (bo[i] > '9')) {
            return new String(bo, 0, i);
        }
    }
    return "-1";
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, then just do `int pid = Integer.parseInt(new File("/proc/self").getCanonicalFile().getName());`. Why the extra gyrations?

Comment: For the curious, the trick in @David 's comment actually works. Can someone say why? Some sort of magic in the `getCanonicalFile()` method that converts "self" to the PID?

Comment: getCanonicalFile() resolves the symlink /proc/self/ -> /proc/1234, try ls -al /proc/self

Comment: @DavidCitron +1! you are right, I did not think in getCanonicalFile :-)

Answer (score 24):

Since Java 9 there is a method [`Process.pid()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#pid--) which returns the native ID of a process:

```
public abstract class Process {

    ...

    public long pid();
}
```

To get the process ID of the current Java process one can use the `ProcessHandle` interface:

```
System.out.println(ProcessHandle.current().pid());
```

Comment: Can you explain how to get a Process instance for the current running process in Java 9?

Comment: Great answer for using Java 9 in 2016! Can you add a link to the javadocs? thanks

Answer (score 18):

You can check out my project: [JavaSysMon](http://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/) on GitHub. It provides process id and a bunch of other stuff (CPU usage, memory usage) cross-platform (presently Windows, Mac OSX, Linux and Solaris)

Comment: Is it possible to get the PID of a Process started by Java? Or start a Process "your way" to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0]
```

Answer (score 10):

In Scala:

```
import sys.process._
val pid: Long = Seq("sh", "-c", "echo $PPID").!!.trim.toLong
```

This should give you a workaround on Unix systems until Java 9 will be released.
(I know, the question was about Java, but since there is no equivalent question for Scala, I wanted to leave this for Scala users who might stumble into the same question.)

Comment: (looks good for Linux and macOS, but I don't know if it would work on Windows)

Comment: Starting an entire new subprocess just to get the PID which is already available in the process itself is pretty overblown. Also, this won't work on Windows since it has no "sh" command (usually).

Answer (score 9):

For completeness there is a wrapper in **Spring Boot** for the

```
String jvmName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
return jvmName.split("@")[0];
```

solution. If an integer is required, then this can be summed up to the one-liner:

```
int pid = Integer.parseInt(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0]);
```

If someone uses Spring boot already, she/he might use *org.springframework.boot.ApplicationPid*

```
ApplicationPid pid = new ApplicationPid();
pid.toString();
```

The toString() method prints the pid or '???'.

Caveats using the ManagementFactory are discussed in other answers already.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static long getPID() {
    String processName = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    if (processName != null && processName.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(processName.split("@")[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

With Java 10, to get `process id`

```
final RuntimeMXBean runtime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
final long pid = runtime.getPid();
out.println("Process ID is '" + pid);
```

Answer (score 5):

The latest I have found is that there is a *system property* called `sun.java.launcher.pid` that is available at least on linux.  My plan is to use that and if it is not found to use the `JMX bean`.

Comment: In my case with Ubuntu 16.04 and Java 8, it returns null

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where you are looking for the information from.

If you are looking for the information from the console you can use the jps command. The command gives output similar to the Unix ps command and comes with the JDK since I believe 1.5

If you are looking from the process the RuntimeMXBean (as said by Wouter Coekaerts) is probably your best choice. The output from getName() on Windows using Sun JDK 1.6 u7 is in the form [PROCESS_ID]@[MACHINE_NAME]. You could however try to execute jps and parse the result from that:

```
String jps = [JDK HOME] + "\\bin\\jps.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jps);
```

If run with no options the output should be the process id followed by the name.

Comment: JPS tool uses jvmstat library, part of tools.jar. Check my example or see JPS source code:
http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java/?v=source. There is no need to call JPS as external process, use jvmstat library directly.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code JConsole, and potentially jps and VisualVM uses. It utilizes classes from
`sun.jvmstat.monitor.*` package, from `tool.jar`.

```
package my.code.a003.process;

import sun.jvmstat.monitor.HostIdentifier;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitorException;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVm;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredVmUtil;
import sun.jvmstat.monitor.VmIdentifier;


public class GetOwnPid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetOwnPid().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getPid(this.getClass()));
    }

    public Integer getPid(Class<?> mainClass) {
        MonitoredHost monitoredHost;
        Set<Integer> activeVmPids;
        try {
            monitoredHost = MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost(new HostIdentifier((String) null));
            activeVmPids = monitoredHost.activeVms();
            MonitoredVm mvm = null;
            for (Integer vmPid : activeVmPids) {
                try {
                    mvm = monitoredHost.getMonitoredVm(new VmIdentifier(vmPid.toString()));
                    String mvmMainClass = MonitoredVmUtil.mainClass(mvm, true);
                    if (mainClass.getName().equals(mvmMainClass)) {
                        return vmPid;
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (mvm != null) {
                        mvm.detach();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (java.net.URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MonitorException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

There are few catches:

- The `tool.jar` is a library distributed with Oracle JDK but not JRE!
- You cannot get `tool.jar` from Maven repo; configure it with Maven is a bit tricky
- The `tool.jar` probably contains platform dependent (native?) code so it is not easily 
   distributable
- It runs under assumption that all (local) running JVM apps are "monitorable". It looks like
   that from Java 6 all apps generally are (unless you actively configure opposite)
- It probably works only for Java 6+
- Eclipse does not publish main class, so you will not get Eclipse PID easily
  Bug in MonitoredVmUtil?

UPDATE: I have just double checked that JPS uses this way, that is Jvmstat library (part of tool.jar). So there is no need to call JPS as external process, call Jvmstat library directly as my example shows. You can aslo get list of all JVMs runnin on localhost this way.
See JPS [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java/?v=source):

Comment: if mainClass.getName() does not work try to use mainClass.getCanonicalName();

Answer (score 2):

Based on Ashwin Jayaprakash's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134967/246622) (+1)
about the Apache 2.0 licensed `SIGAR`, here is how I use it to get only the PID of the current process:

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;

Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
long pid = sigar.getPid();
sigar.close();
```

Even though it does not work on all platforms, it does work on [Linux, Windows, OS X and various Unix platforms as listed here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404171332/https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home#Home-overview).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to call out that API for getting the PID (as well as other manipulation of the Java process at runtime) is being added to the Process class in JDK 9: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102

Comment: Wow, that was fast. It only took about seven years! 

Answer (score 1):

You can try `getpid()` in [JNR-Posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix).

It has a Windows POSIX wrapper that calls getpid() off of libc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that may be a bit of an edge case and I didn't try it on other OS than Windows 10, but I think it's worth noticing.

If you find yourself working with [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) and nodejs, you can run a simple javascript function returning you the pid of the java process.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NodeJS nodeJS = NodeJS.createNodeJS();
    int pid = nodeJS.getRuntime().executeIntegerScript("process.pid;\n");
    System.out.println(pid);
    nodeJS.release();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
public static boolean isPIDInUse(int pid) {

        try {

            String s = null;
            int java_pid;

            RuntimeMXBean rt = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
            java_pid = Integer.parseInt(rt.getName().substring(0, rt.getName().indexOf("@")));

            if (java_pid == pid) {
                System.out.println("In Use\n");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:  " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This does not check if pid is in use, but if pid equals current process pid

Comment: What is the correct solution so i can update my code?

Answer (score -6):

This is what I used when I had similar requirement. This determines the PID of the Java process correctly. Let your java code spawn a server on a pre-defined port number and then execute OS commands to find out the PID listening on the port. For Linux

```
netstat -tupln | grep portNumber
```

Comment: If you're calling shell scripts, you might as well do something simpler like `bash -c 'echo $PPID'` or the /proc [answers above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id#comment8446374_6372205)