# Get a Process Object by Process Id

Tags: java, winapi, process, jna

how can I get a Process object by a certain ProcessId in Java.

I am using JNA to create a process, because I want to open a application in the background.

```
WinBase.STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new WinBase.STARTUPINFO();
startupInfo.dwFlags = 1;

WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation = new WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();

Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(null, "C:\\Program Files\\...", null, null, true, new WinDef.DWORD(0), Pointer.NULL, System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), startupInfo, processInformation);

int prozessId = processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue();
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Process?  How to you *not* open a process in the background in Java?

Comment: I have try this, but my application did always start in the foreground. I am using the ProcessBuilder for this

Comment: I suppose this question is rather about Windows API programming than Java!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683427/launch-application-in-a-minimized-state-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. The API for `Process` and `ProcessBuilder` don't allow you to create `Process` instances for existing processes; you can always only create new child processes with them.