# Running background process and getting it periodically with GUI when user opens

Tags: java

I want to have a long running process (running for days, or even weeks) and the user will be able to close the GUI application and keep the process running (in background).

I am writing in Java, and people have hinted at using Sockets to have a long running process that you can check a socket for (as suggested here [Start Java program only if not already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660205/start-java-program-only-if-not-already-running)), but I'm not sure that's exactly what I want.

The idea is similar to GIMPS (or primenet), users have long computation running, but they can open up GUI to view log of the process.

Any help is appreciated.