# How to close a program if is already open in Java

Tags: java, interprocess

I'm writing this server, and I want to check if the same program is already running, if is running close the program.

Say I run ServerA

Then I run ServerB (which is the same server)

I want to close ServerA so ServerB can run successfully.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660205/start-java-program-only-if-not-already-running) answers your query.

Comment: `ServerB` would require admin privileges to close `ServerA`.

Comment: Calling out to `pkill` might be a simple solution. Though it might be easier to do it in a shell script that wraps your program rather than building this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I manage to do it like so...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String PIDtoKill = readPIDFile();
    if(!PIDtoKill.isEmpty())
        killPID(PIDtoKill);
    saveThisPIDtoFile();
}
```

Method used....

```
private static String readPIDFile() {
    try {
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\PIDsRunning.txt")))
            return line;
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

private static void saveThisPIDtoFile() {
    String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    pid = pid.substring(0, pid.indexOf("@"));

    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(pid);
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\PIDsRunning.txt");

    try {
        Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void killPID(String pIDtoKill) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID " + pIDtoKill);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind if you take this route that for cross-platform support (past Windows) you'll need to find the OS and Call an OS appropriate equivalent command to 'taskkill'

Comment: thanks , I know but this is just for devoloping purposes, and maybe i leave it as it is, cuz this program will be running on a windows VPS.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to close the program if it is open
You can go for:
System.exit(0);

There are many other exit codes but 0 seems to suit your requirement.

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to close the current program, I want to close the program that ran first so that the newer program can run

Answer (score 0):

Using the system to kill the process by pid is *one* solution.

One can use **RMI** (Remote Method Invocation) to create single instance applications, or in your case send a kill call so the application can terminate on its own. *(A graceful termination, requiring the app to be still functioning.)*

You could also use an **OSGi** container: that play with module life cycles the best.