# Clean Java 7 way to create file if not exists

Tags: java, file-io, nio

What is the Java 7 or Java 8 way to create a file if that does not exists?

Comment: AFAIK Java 8 doesn't change the way we work with files.

Comment: @alfasin Java 7 (and therefore Java 8 as well) has changed it immensely with java.nio.file; and today, unfortunately, it is still underused

Comment: @fge Quite true. I'll remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a file in Java only if one doesn't already exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556127/how-to-create-a-file-in-java-only-if-one-doesnt-already-exist).

Comment: @Joe like I said in an earlier comment, this question does not provide any solution with java.nio.file. This is 2015! What is more, this question explicity mentions Java 7+.

Comment: For what purpose? Normally you don't just create files, you write to them, in which case you just use a `new FileOutputStream(...)` or whatever. Asking for a Java 7 or 8 solution requires motivation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but for instance:

```
try {
    Files.createFile(thePath);
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException ignored) {
}
```

And there are other solutions; for instance:

```
if (!Files.exists(thePath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS))
    Files.createFile(thePath);
```

Note that unlike `File`, these will throw exceptions if file creation fails! And relevant ones at that (for instance, `AccessDeniedException`, `ReadOnlyFileSystemException`, etc etc)

See [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API) for more information. Also see [why you should migrate to `java.nio.file`, quickly](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks).

Comment: So there is no one line code to do that?

Comment: No, but does it really matter? ;) You can just create your own utility method if you want, this is not really a problem

Comment: try { Files.createFile(thePath); } catch(FileAlreadyExistsException ignored){}

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
File f = new File("pathToYourFile");
if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())
{
    f.createNewFile()
}
```

If you want to use NIO.2 you can use methods Files class.

```
boolean exists(Path path,LinkOption. . . options)
Path createTempFile(Path dir, String prefix,String suffix, FileAttribute<?>. . . attrs)
createFile(Path path, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
```

As fge has mentioned in the comments `createNewFile()` methods returns `boolean` value denoting if file was actually created or not. Unfortunately there is no way to know why it failed. In fact this is one of the reason NIO.2 I/O APIs were introduced.

Comment: And... You don't check the result of `.createNewFile()`!