# Using java FileChannel FileLock to prevent file writes but allow reads

Tags: java, windows, locking, readwritelock

I think I'm misunderstanding how the `FileChannel`'s locking features work.

I want to have an exclusive write lock on a file, but allow reads from any process.

On a Windows 7 machine running Java 7, I can get `FileChannel`'s lock to work, but it prevents both reads and writes from other processes.

How can I achieve a file lock that disallows writes but allows reads by other processes?

Answer (score 6):

- `FileChannel.lock()` deals with file regions, not with the file itself.
- The lock can be either shared (many readers, no writers) or exclusive (one writer and no readers).

I guess you are looking for a bit different feature - to *open* a file for writing while allowing other processes to open it for reading but not for writing.

This can be achieved by Java 7 [FileChannel.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) API with non-standard open option:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import static com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedOpenOption.*;
...
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("noshared.tmp");
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(path, CREATE, WRITE, NOSHARE_WRITE);
```

Note `ExtendedOpenOption.NOSHARE_WRITE` which is a non-standard option existing in Oracle JDK.

Comment: bah :-( why do they make it exist in `com.sun.*` but not available to the user?

Comment: @JasonS It IS available to user (if you are running Oracle JDK or OpenJDK).

Comment: You'll need `NOSHARE_DELETE`, too - so the File can't be deleted by other processes (`FileChannel.lock()` prevents deletions)