# Lock file for writing?

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I lock a file using java (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible)

Is it possible to lock file so that other apps cannot write to file but can still run it normally?
My target platform is windows.

Comment: i think that FileLock locks file for both running and writing?

Answer (score 0):

```
File yourFile = new File("yourFile.txt");

yourFile.setWritable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [FileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)'s [lock() API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29).