# Locking `properties` file in java

Tags: java, properties, nio, filelock

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible) post. Can anybody tell me if the `java.nio.FileLock.lock()` works well with `java.util.Properties` class.

Question:

If I put the lock on the properties file what I read, does this lock the file for other concurrent locking? The code Will lock something like:

```
try {

     Properties prop = new Properties();
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/my/path"));
     FileLock lock = fis.getChannel().lock();
     prop.load(fis);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   //catch it...
} catch (IOException e) {
   //catch it...
}

//....
lock.release();
//...
```

Thanks!

---

From *JavaDocs*:

1.*The locks held on a particular file by a single Java virtual machine do not overlap.*

and

2.a.*File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.*

b.*File-lock objects are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.*

Related to 1: I tried to lock on the same file from the same JVM but from different threads, and it throws errors when a thread tried to put lock on the already locked file. I think that behavior is not how expected from the *JavaDoc* specifications.

Related to 2 a and b: It seems to me that they're contradicting. Am I right? If not, can anyone explain me what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

File locks are generally advisory: that is, they only affect other processes, e.g. JVMs, that are also using file locks. `java.util.Properties` doesn't do that at all, but then it doesn't process files either, only input streams. So if you provide the input streams from files that you are setting/checking file locks on, it will work. But only *between* JVMs, not *within a single JVM:* see the Javadoc.