# Java accessing a file among threads at the same time

Tags: java, file, concurrency, blocking

I have some confusions on java file lock.

here's my situation.

1. Each thread can read/write a file.
2. My file manipulating method can be called by several threads at the same time

and, my goal is clear, no concurrent write to a file by threads. Always one thread allowed to write a file.

My questions are

1. If FileOutputStream.write() was thread safe, I didn't have to put any concurrency  mechanism in my code since the code at the write() will block until a locked file will be released. However, my program would not seem to block when a file is opened by a thread (i am not sure for this)
2. If FileOutputStream.write() was NOT thread safe, I would have to write additional code to make a file accessed by only thread at a time. Therefore, I used FileChannel.lock() to do so. However, different from the JDK document it does not block but throw an OverlappingFileLockException.

I would appreciate your clear advise.

Comment: FWIW FileChannel#lock is to lock out *other processes* not to synchronize between threads of the same JVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible

Comment: Thanks to your reference. So.. FileChannel.lock() is only valid among processes not threads? and I really have to use synchronizing approach... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not thread safe and you need to programmatically ensure safety. Just put the relevant code in a synchronized block assuming there is no major performance requirement for your app.

Comment: Synchronized block on the method is not my option like you mentioned. File reading/writing is major job on my app. If each thread is accessing different files, they don't need to be synchronized. I hope write() method blocked when file is opened with least additional code. if it's not possible i will have to  determine whether a file is accessed by different thread by my self (string match...etc)

Comment: You could have the synchronized block use some object representing the file as a lock. Doesn't have to be global.