# How do I solve problems in my screenshot-taking application?

Tags: java, image, io

I wrote a GUI-based Java program that takes 25 screenshots per second and saves them at a user-defined location.
It works pretty well except that it has two problems:

The mouse cursor is missing from the images and I know it will be because `BufferedImage`s do not contain cursor information in them. They have to be added programatically.

The thread that takes screenshots is a daemon thread. So if I close the application, the thread is killed and the PNG image that was being written gets corrupted. I want to avoid that.

Here are the images of my application:
**The award-winning, intuitive GUI**:
[image]

**The high-definition images captured look like this**:
[image]
As you can see from the image the cursor information is being displayed in the console using `MouseInfo`'s static methods.

Please let me know how to solve the above mentioned two problems.
**After solving the problem, the images now look like this:**
[image: with cursor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The mouse cursor is missing from the images and I know it will be
>   because BufferedImages do not contain cursor information in them. They
>   have to be added programatically.

That is correct, you have to add the cursor afterwards. The reason for this is that a screenshot taken with the Robot class never contains the cursor. Not really because "the BufferedImage doesn't contain mouse info". A BufferedImage is a class that contains a raster of pixels.

> The thread that takes screenshots is a daemon thread. So if I close
>   the application, the thread is killed and the PNG image that was being
>   written gets corrupted. I want to avoid that.

Simply, in the screenshot thread, use a flag that indicates wether it should continue or not. Keep taking screenshots as long as that boolean is set to true. Make sure to make it non-deamon. So, when you close the application, set the flag to false.
Probably the most easy way to do this is to add a WindowListener:

```
yourFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
    {
        screenshotThread.stopTakingScreenshots(); // This methods set the flag
    }
}
```

---

Also notice that you are not taking the time it takes to make and save a screenshot in count. You use a fixed sleep of 40 milliseconds, but let's say that it takes 4 milliseconds to take and save the screenshot, then you should sleep for only 36 milliseconds. To time how long it takes to make the screenshot, use `System.currentTimeMillis();` before and after your `takeShot()` method and make the difference.

Comment: this can be done by implementing the `finalize()` method for the GUI window where I set the flag to false? and second, please tell me more about the first issue.

Comment: The application thread should wait for the screenshot thread to signal that it is finished.  This would be in the application close method.

Comment: Reading up on destroy(), hang on! :)

Comment: `You use a fixed sleep of 40 milliseconds` Im so proud that my program takes such high-def images that you could read what was in the screenshot. :p Kidding!

Comment: Just to keep you updated, both the problems have been solved.

Comment: @DummyDerp: How did you add the cursor to the screenshots? Is is a pseudo cursor you drew (like a simple square or circle), or the real cursor image on that moment of recording?

Comment: The whole code is not needed. Just some simple references of the techniques you used. Yesterday, I googled a bit on how to do it. But I couldn't find out.

Comment: and another question: How do I lock the folder to which I am writing the images?

Comment: `Graphics2D g2D =(Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();` obtain Graphics2D and then draw the required image on the `BufferedImage`
    `g2D.drawImage(((ImageIcon)selectedCursor).getImage(),myCursorPoint.x,myCursorPoint.y,SCapGUI.this);`

Comment: Yes, that part is pretty obvious. But how to you get the current cursor image?

Comment: Oh, I see, you are not using the real cursor. Just a image of a default cursor. But when the cursor changes, because you are on a button, the recording will not show a hand, but the arrow.

Comment: That is correct. Sorry I deleted the posts so that I can post them back in a more organised manner.

Comment: 1. Create an `ImageIcon` object that stores the image of your cursor. 2. When editing the `BufferedImage` just call the `getImage()` method and it will return a `Image` object as required by the `draw()` method

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux How do I lock the folder to which I am writing the images?

Comment: I don't know. That depends on your OS for sure. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible