# How to convert BufferedImage to AVI?

Tags: java, video, image-processing, bufferedreader

This question is an extension to my previous question:
[Problems associated with my screenshot-taking software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375399/how-do-i-solve-problems-in-my-screenshot-taking-application)
Now with the problems solved, I want to convert the `.png` images to `.avi` file. Now the format of images and video doesn't really matter since the images are written to the disk using `javax.swing.ImageIO` so I can change the save format. So they are `BufferedImage` before being made as `.png`
Most questions here on similar topics were asked to use some 3rd party software and all. I want to do it using just Java.
Where do I begin?
Can you [help me understand this?](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx)

Comment: Going over https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1262127 and the answer provided there is simply so genius!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries you might want to take look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler). It's a wrapper for ffmpeg that helped me some time ago.

**Update:** This demo might contain all you need: https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/CaptureScreenToFile.java

Comment: It looks daunting. The tutorials, too!

Comment: I agree, the online tutorials are sub par.

Comment: please lets stick to the java that comes from Oracle :p

Comment: Alright, never trust a file format you have not parsed yourself. ;)

Comment: never try to learn something advanced about Java when you haven't even done the basics well :p

Comment: is there anything simpler than [this](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx)

Comment: Xuggler tutorials have gone away!