# Deny read access to a file till the write is complete - java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a requirement where in I write a file to server. Another application has a scheduled job which reads the file at a specific interval. The file shouldn't be readable till my write is complete. I have tried using

```
File.isReadable(false)
```

But this is not working. And the scheduler is picking up the incomplete data from the file, if I am still writing to it.

Any Solutions?

Comment: How about [getting a lock on the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another file with same name as marker. You will start writing into `FileName.txt` and when is finished, create file `FileName.rdy`
And your application will check only for *.rdy files, if found - read FileName.txt.

Answer (score 5):

Write to a different file name and then when the write is complete rename the file to the name the scheduler expects.  If you're running on Linux or similar then file renames within the same file system are atomic.

```
File tempFile = new File("/path/to/file.tmp");
// write to tempFile
tempFile.renameTo(new File("/path/to/file"));
```

Comment: If you're using Java 7, better use the new `Files` API.

Comment: @Ian My app runs on windows. The App reading the file is on Solaris. And the file server is Linux. Meaning the file and the apps are on different physical machines

Comment: @sadhu it may still be worth a try, or if you have control over the app reading the file then [JIV's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16813659/592139) is probably the best way to go.

Comment: This is a smart, simple and reliable solution that should work in almost any scenario. I like it. Can only +1 unfortunately.

Comment: @Ian I am already on it. Will update the forum once I am through. Yes, I do have control on both the apps.

Comment: @Ian JIV's answer worked well. I should have already thought about it as Autosys FileWatcher jobs does the same:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) API.

I explained briefly how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788740/java-file-locking-mechanism-for-file-based-process-communication/16788810#16788810).

Answer (score 0):

the better option would be to synchronize the read and write procedures...

put your code to read file and write file in synchornized {} blocks....such that one can wait till other completes

Comment: The read is happening in "another application", and you can't use `synchronized` across separate processes.