# What is the mechanism to ensure that 2 different process should not read\write to the same file at a time in java

Tags: java

I m working in java. I have an application which will read & write one sample.txt file.
And one more application which will also read & write to same file.
And first application will run for every 1 minute as windows service.
My doubt is now how, can make sure that both applications should r/w at the same time.
Any suggestions plz.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible

Answer (score 3):

As you want to lock access from different application if i understand it right. You can use FileLock here an [example](http://ourownjava.com/how-to-create-file-lock-in-java)

Comment: Here. This is the right answer. People nowadays reads questions too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You need to guard the file access code through [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) block or methods. Learn more about synchronization here:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html

Comment: this would only work within **one** java application

Answer (score 0):

Simples solution is to use the synchronized keyword.

```
public synchronized int i = 1;
```

in this way i can only be accessed from one thread at the time. But this is expansive! There are many concepts of synchronization, e.g. the monitor

Read this for more information: http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html

Comment: this would only work within **one** java application

Comment: this will work in one jvm