# Java inter-process mutex

Tags: java, locking, mutex

I need to implement some kind of inter-process mutex in Java. I'm considering using the FileLock API as recommended in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible). I'll basically be using a dummy file and locking it in each process.

Is this the best approach? Or is something like this built in the standard API (I can't find it).

**For more details see below:**

I have written an application which reads some input files and updates some database tables according to what it finds in them (it's more complex, but business logic is irrelevant here).

I need to ensure mutual exclusion between multiple database updates. I tried to implement this with LOCK TABLE, but this is unsupported by the engine I'm using. So, I want to implement the locking support in the application code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went for the FileLock API approach and implemented a simple mutex based on:

- [FileChannel.lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29)
- [FileLock.release](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html#release%28%29)

All the processes use the same dummy file for acquiring locks.

Comment: how is your program now, is it still running, does it need to update to more global lock? just curious after years

Answer (score 2):

Why bother using files, if you have database on your hands? Try using database locking like this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

By the way, what database engine do you use? It might help if you list it.

Comment: The engine will be Brighthouse. But it doesn't support any type of locking, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: May be unrelated to the question, but what is the reason to use database engine which doesn't allow any tools for concurrent data modification?

Comment: It's very good for high performance queries with lots of data. But it has some limitations compared to standard MySQL engines.

Comment: Got it. But when using MySQL or alike engines concurrency and it's tuning was the most headache-causing issue (deadlocks and so on). If I knew it is bound to a single client/connection I would most definetely increased it performance quite a lot (as I do for some local installations when no AJAX meaning parallel queries is involved).