# Is a Java FileLock a POSIX advisory (fcntl) lock

Tags: java, linux, posix, file-locking, fcntl

I have a C++ program that locks files using POSIX advisory locks. That is, it uses the [POSIX `fcntl` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html) for lock operations. I want a Java program to interoperate with that C++ program, so I want my Java program to also use POSIX advisory locks. File locking in Java [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible) use the standard [`FileLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) class. But the API documentation is understandably vague on just how locking is implemented:

> This file-locking API is intended to map directly to the native locking facility of the underlying operating system. Thus the locks held on a file should be visible to all programs that have access to the file, regardless of the language in which those programs are written.

If I am running a common implementation of Java (Oracles, Open JDK) on a POSIX operating system, or more specifically a GNU/Linux system, is it safe to assume that the Java `FileLock` class uses POSIX advisory locks?

Comment: What choice does it have?

Comment: @EJP The alternative would be to use a BSD `flock` system call. Which might or might not be implemented using `fcntl`.

Comment: @EJP ... but looking more closely, I see that `flock` does not support record-level locking.

Comment: Also ["The flock(), fcntl(2), and lockf(3) locks are compatible"](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2). So there's nothing left for this question to be about.

Comment: Unless something has recently changed `flock` is incompatible with `fcntl` (and `lockf`) on Linux.  The two are essentially invisible to one another.  So there is indeed a point to this question.

Comment: [(OReilly, Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3ed, 2005](http://idak.gop.edu.tr/esmeray/UnderStandingKernel.pdf):
"Both the fcntl() and the flock() system call may be used on the same file at the same time, but a file locked through fcntl() does not appear locked to flock(), and vice versa. This has been done on purpose in order to avoid the deadlocks occurring when an application using a type of lock relies on a library that uses the other type."

Comment: [OReilly, Understanding the Linux Kernel, 2nd, sec 12.7](http://anselmo.homeunix.net/ebooks/linuxkernel2/083.htm):
A lock produced by fcntl() is of type FL_POSIX, while a lock produced by flock() is of type FL_FLOCK, FL_MAND (for share-mode locks), or FL_LEASE (for leases). The types of locks produced by fcntl() may safely coexist with those produced by flock(), but neither one has any effect on the other. Therefore, a file locked through fcntl() does not appear locked to flock(), and vice versa.

Comment: To complicate matters further, there is work on a new type of lock, file-private POSIX locks: http://lwn.net/Articles/586904/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Unix operating systems, including Linux, provide [BSD-style (`flock`) locks](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2), so it might be thought that Java `FileLock` could be implemented using BSD-style locks rather than [POSIX locks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html). But that is not possible, because BSD-style locks are *whole-file* locks rather than *record* locks, and  `FileLock` is a record lock: each lock is for a range of bytes in a file. Thus there is no real choice on a Unix system, and assuming that the implementation of `FileLock` uses POSIX `fcntl` locks is a safe assumption on a Unix operating system.

The resulting `FileLock` locks might or might not interact with BSD-style locks. BSD-style locks can be implemented using POSIX locks ([this was the case for Linux before version 2.0](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html)), or the operating system might have the two styles of locking interact ([this is the case for FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2)). But in general that can not be guaranteed, and BSD-style locks and Java locks might be effectively invisible to each other ([this is the case for any version of Linux you are likely to encounter](http://anselmo.homeunix.net/ebooks/linuxkernel2/083.htm)).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

(1) Write a small java program that locks a file and sleeps (or otherwise stops executing).

(2) cat /proc/locks

(3) You'll see lines like the following:

```
24: POSIX  ADVISORY  READ  1784 08:01:27384070 1073742826 1073742335
25: FLOCK  ADVISORY  WRITE 815  00:0f:9772     0          EOF
```

Identify your process ID from column 5.  If column 2 is FLOCK then `flock` is being used.  If it is POSIX then column 2 will be POSIX, indicating fcntl (or `lockf` which is build on top of `fcntl`) is being used.

If java has to choose one or the other then POSIX would be the sensible choice as it supports record locking.