# How can my thread mark a file as in use so other threads won't read it?

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a Java application that watches a directory and when XML files are added to that directory, it parses out data from the XML file.

It works file as a single-threaded application, but I'm thinking out making it multi-threaded so multiple files can be processed simultaneously.

Question is, when thread #1 finds a file and starts processing it, how can I mark the file as 'in progress' so thread #2 doesn't try to process it to?

I was thinking that the thread could simply rename the file once it starts working on it, to `myfile.xml.inprogress`, and then `myfile.xml.finished` when done.

But if I do that, is it possible that two threads will see the file at the same time and both will try to rename it simultaneously?

I might also want to run two instances of this application reading files in the same directory, so whatever path I take supports multiple processes.

Thanks!

Comment: @Mikrobus If thread#1 creates a new File() for the file, is thread#2 prevented from creating a new File() for the same file?  What about if thread#2 is in a different process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible

Comment: I would probably have one "monitor/scheduler" thread and multiple processor threads. Monitor thread schedules jobs in-memory for processor threads. You can have better in-memory locking this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `Producer-Consumer` pattern. Have one thread to listen for changes in the files and pass off that work to other threads.

You can use a `BlockingQueue` for this to make the code very simple.

First you need two classes, a producer:

```
class Producer implements Callable<Void> {

    private final BlockingQueue<Path> changedFiles;

    Producer(BlockingQueue<Path> changedFiles) {
        this.changedFiles = changedFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            if (something) {
                changedFiles.add(changedFile);
            }
            //to make the thread "interruptable"
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And a `Consumer`:

```
class Consumer implements Callable<Void> {

    private final BlockingQueue<Path> changedFiles;

    Consumer(BlockingQueue<Path> changedFiles) {
        this.changedFiles = changedFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            try {
                final Path changedFile = changedFiles.take();
                //process your file
            //to make the thread "interruptable"
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, now create an `ExecutorService`, submit one `Producer` and as many consumers as you need:

```
final BlockingQueue<Path> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final Collection<Future<?>> consumerHandles = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numConsumers; ++i) {
    consumerHandles.add(executorService.submit(new Consumer(queue)));
}
final Future<?> producerHandle = executorService.submit(new Producer(queue));
```

So you guarantee that only one file is being worked on at a time because you control that yourself. You also do so with minimum synchronisation.

It might be worthwhile the `Consumer` also *reading* the file to remove the the shared disc IO that will happen otherwise - this will likely slow the system down. You could also add another `Consumer` that writes changed files at the other end to completely eliminate shared IO.

To shutdown the system simply call:

```
executorService.shutdownNow();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Because your workers are interruptible this will bring down the `ExectuorService` once tasks currently in progress have finished.

Answer (score 0):

Producer Consumer is definitely the idea here.

With `Java 7` there is a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) provided which can take care of the `Producer` problem even though it is a pain to work with.

Have an `ExecutorService` with the desired pool size to take care of `Consumers`.

Here is it how it all wires up.

```
public class FolderWatchService {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public void watch() throws Exception {
        Path folder = Paths.get("/home/user/temp");
        try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {

            folder.register(watchService,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
            while(true) {
                final WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                if (key != null) {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                        WatchEvent<Path> event = (WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent;
                        Path dir = (Path) key.watchable();
                        Path absolutePath = dir.resolve(event.context());
                        executorService.submit(new WatchTask(absolutePath));
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FolderWatchService folderWatchService = new FolderWatchService();
        folderWatchService.watch();
    }

}
class WatchTask implements Runnable {

    private Path absolutePath;

    WatchTask(Path absolutePath) {
        this.absolutePath = absolutePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + absolutePath.toAbsolutePath());
         try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(absolutePath , StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
             //Do read
             reader.lines().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this might well produce an infinite loop if the reader then writes.

Comment: while (true) is an infinite loop definitely either way since I am not exiting. while (conditionToExit) would be a better way. But this code sample is supposed to be a pointer not production ready.

Comment: No, I mean that you have a loop where a write to a file immediately causes the `WatchService` to pick up the change and queue it for processing. Which would cause another thread to pick up the _same_ file. Now when either of those two threads writes the file will be queued again...

Comment: Ah.. got your point. Wouldn't listening to just creation events resolve that issue. `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE`

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use `java.nio.channels.FileLock`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html to synchronize access between different processes.
2. For synchronization between different threads running inside the same process, you can use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Comment: No you can't. See the Javadoc. It's for use between processes, not threads.

Comment: @EJP Multiple processes were actually mentioned in the question.

Comment: And so were multiple threads, at much greater length, starting with the title, and so was the fact that vhatever path he takes has to support both.

Comment: @user2040251 Thanks for the help, I found your answer useful.

Comment: @RobertHume Given the wording of your question I don't see how that's possible.