# Lock a file in Java with FileLock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to write to a file, using a [Java FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html), to prohibit all other processes and threads from reading from it or writing to it until I'm finished with it. Given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible) and the answers to it, it seems to me like this is the perfect tool for what I want--a mutex for file access.

However, I am very concerned about this text from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html):

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They
>   are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads
>   within the same virtual machine.

Can someone either alleviate my fears or point me in the right direction? It sounds like `FileLock` won't work at all to keep a different thread out of the file, even if another thread has already obtained it. If this is the case, is there another canonical Java method to do this that will protect from other threads?

Comment: Use normal mutual exclusion methods (`synchronized` blocks or `ReentrantLocks`) to keep threads from accessing the same resources at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FileLock` is a process level lock and will thus not protect the file from concurrent access from multiple threads within the process that has the lock.

You need to use a combination of the `FileLock` to protect from concurrent access from other processes and some other synchronization mechanism (like a `synchronized` method for accessing the file) within your process to protect from concurrent access by your own threads.

Answer (score 2):

I would implement this as follows:

```
interface FileOperator {
  public void operate(File file);
}

class FileProxy {
  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<URI, FileProxy> map =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private final Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, true);

  private final File file;

  private final URI key;

  private FileProxy(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    this.key = file.toURI();
  }

  public static void operate(URI uri, FileOperator operator) {
    FileProxy curProxy = map.get(uri);
    if(curProxy == null) {
      FileProxy newProxy = new FileProxy(new File(uri));
      FileProxy curProxy = map.putIfAbsent(newProxy.key, newProxy);
      if(curProxy == null) {
        curProxy = newProxy; // FileProxy was not in the map
      }
    }

    try {
      curProxy.mutex.acquire();
      operator.operate(curProxy.file);
    } finally {
      curProxy.mutex.release();
    }
  }
}
```

The threads that are using a file implement `FileOperator` or something similar.  Files are hidden behind a `FileProxy` that maintains a static `ConcurrentHashMap` of key (URI, or absolute path, or some other file invariant) value (`FileProxy`) pairs.  Each `FileProxy` maintains a `Semaphore` that acts as a mutex - this is initialized with one permit.  When the static `operate` method is called, a new `FileProxy` is created from the URI if none exists; the `FileOperator` is then added to the `FileProxy` queue; `acquire` is called on the mutex to ensure that only one thread can operate on the file at a time; and finally the `FileOperator` does its thing.

In this implementation, `FileProxy` objects are never removed from the `ConcurrentHashMap` - if this is a problem then a solution is to wrap the `FileProxy` objects in a `WeakReference` or `SoftReference` so that they can be garbage collected, and then call `map.replace` if `reference.get() == null` to ensure that only one thread replaces the GC'd reference.