# Java : How to block other program from accessing file if one program is using it?

Tags: java

I have 2-3 programs which can modify file but I want to block others if one program is using it. I cant use synchronization in this. Is there any other provision ?

Comment: Do you actually mean different programs, or different threads in the same program?

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible

Comment: @Jaydee's suggestion is what I'd normally use. However, the documentation says: "Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified." Make sure this is not a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file locking over different application it isn't at Java level handled.
You must handle it at OS level. Different OS has different solutions.

> I want to block others if one program is using it.

Probably you want to have a write lock, excluding all readers and writers. But allowing some of your programs. At windows maybe present this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx) interest.

It is very platform dependent, but is a Java code to try it:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    java.nio.channels.FileLock lock = in.getChannel().lock();
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is Java API for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/128168/718590