# Concurrent read and write from different programs in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm writing two programs that communicate through a text file. The first program writes to the file and the second one reads from it. However, there is a problem when the reader program tries to read from the file while the writer is still writing and reads inconsistent data. Is there a way to synchronize the read/write from two different JVMs?

Comment: Any reason for this approach? Do you *have* to use a text file?

Comment: Yes, I have to use a text file.

Comment: Would you tell use why? Why not a socket? Why not a message passing library?

Comment: It's not up to me. I was assigned this specific task as a part of the bigger project.

Comment: You could use a file lock (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible) The JVM holding the lock is the one that has access to the file. The other JVM will periodically poll the file, try to acquire the lock.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that is often used:

1. Write the text to a file with a different name than the reader expects. For example, if the expected filename is `abc.txt`, write to a file called `abc.txt.temp`.
2. Once writing is complete, **rename** the file to its intended name. On most (this is platform-dependent, though) filesystems, a rename of a file within the same directory is atomic - it will occur instantly. So in this case, rename is from `abc.txt.tmp` to `abc.txt`. You can use the `java.io.File.renameTo` or `java.nio.Files.move` methods for renaming.

The reader will then only be able to see completely written files in `abc.txt`.