# Check whether the delayed job is running in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am designing a status page where I need to show whether the delayed job is running. Please help me with a way to find it in the code.

Am using 
   Rails 3.0.20, 
   ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352), and 
   delayed_job 3.0.4

Answer (score 23):

With **Rails 5.x** you can ssh into your server and go into the /current folder within your app and run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job status
```

Comment: On my Rails 4 project, the command was

`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status`

Comment: @bayfieldcoder did you upgrade that project from rails 3?

Comment: Yes, I did upgrade it from rails 3.

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status
```

if you are checking in production mode

Answer (score 9):

The most simple way to check whether delayed_job is running or not, is to check at `locked_by` field.

This field will contain the worker or process locking/processing the job.

Running `Delayed::Job.where('locked_by is not null')`  will give you some results, if there are jobs running.

Besides that, you can have a **clockwork task** performing this query, to check at the status.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the best way I can think of to ensure the `delayed_job daemon` is always running, is to add an `initializer` to our Rails application that checks if the daemon is running. If it's not running, then the `initializer` starts the `daemon`, otherwise, it just leaves it be.

Now the question, therefore, is how do we detect that the `Delayed_Job daemon` is running from inside a script?

**The easy way-**

Check for the existence of the daemons `PID file` (File.exist? ...). If it's there then assume it's running else start it up.

Comment: i m working on EC2 with DJ(Active record). I m using 'mina' for deployment. how can i check if DJ is running or not before starting it. The problem is multiple DJ processes are started whenever i deploy.

Comment: How do you start worker in script? Would script/delayed_job restart work?

Answer (score 2):

To check the job status etc you can use [delayed_job_web](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web) gem which enlists all the enqueued jobs. And to  ensure that its running all the time install monit. [Here's](http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit) the railscast. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285611/1087546) more info about how to configure monit for delayed_job

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

pid = ARGV[0].to_i

begin
  Process.kill(0, pid)
  puts "#{pid} is running"
rescue Errno::EPERM                     # changed uid
  puts "No permission to query #{pid}!";
rescue Errno::ESRCH
  puts "#{pid} is NOT running.";      # or zombied
rescue
  puts "Unable to determine status for #{pid} : #{$!}"
end
```

Check [How can I determine if a different process id is running using Java or JRuby on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141162/how-can-i-determine-if-a-different-process-id-is-running-using-java-or-jruby-on/200568#200568)