How to check if delayed_job is alive?
For my client reasons, I have my rails application using delayed_job running on windows. I have a scheduled task to start my app and another one to start the delayed_job console, but sometimes the delayed_job is not starting correctly.
Is there a way to check if the daemon is alive, and if not, start it directly by my rails app?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829435/1592591 This might help you to check the status. Just make sure you are passing correct environment
