# Child process detecting the parent process' death in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there a way for a child process in Python to detect if the parent process has died?

Answer (score 5):

If your Python process is running under Linux, and the `prctl()` system call is exposed, you can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits).

This can cause a signal to be sent to the child when the parent process dies.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the parent is alive when you start to do this, you can check whether it is still alive in a busy loop as such, by using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil, os, time
me = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
while 1:
    if me.parent() is not None:
        # still alive
        time.sleep(0.1)
        continue
    else:
        print("my parent is gone")
        break
```

Not very nice but...

Comment: It's truly incredible, that after 30 years of Python existence there is not an integrated function to get the PPID of any given PID and that one have to resort to a 3rd party plugin, because `os.getppid()` doesn't take any arguments... :(

Comment: Note that `os.getppid()` [returns the old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539184/after-starting-process-how-to-get-parents-pid-in-the-child#23539712) on Windows, so possible race condition. Although psutil "preemptively checking whether PID has been reused" so it should be okay.

Comment: Should be `me.parent()` since `psutil.parent` is a member method.

Answer (score 3):

The only reliable way I know of is to create a pipe specifically for this purpose. The child will have to repeatedly attempt to read from the pipe, preferably in a non-blocking fashion, or using select. It will get an error when the pipe does not exist anymore (presumably because of the parent's death).

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with reading your parent process' ID very early in your process, and then checking, but of course that is prone to race conditions. The parent that did the spawn might have died immediately, and even before your process got to execute its first instruction.

Unless you have a way of verifying if a given PID refers to the "expected" parent, I think it's hard to do reliably.