# After starting process, how to get parent's PID in the child?

Tags: python, process

In Python, I start a new process via `Popen()`, which works fine. Now in the child process I want to find the parent's process ID.

What is the best way to achieve this, maybe I can pass the PID via the `Popen` constructor, but how? Or is there a better way to do so?

PS: If possible I would prefere a solution using only standard libraries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`os.getppid()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getppid):

> `os.getppid()`
>
> ```
> Return the parent’s process id.
> ```

Note: this works only on Unix, not on Windows. On Windows you can use [`os.getpid()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getpid) in the parent process and pass the pid as argument to the process you start with `Popen`.

Windows support for [`os.getppid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getppid) was added in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 15):

Use `psutil` ([here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil))

```
import psutil, os
psutil.Process(os.getpid()).ppid()
```

works both for Unix & Windows (even if `os.getppid()` doesn't exist on this platform)

Comment: Thanks, but if possible I would prefer a solution using only Python standard libraries.

Comment: Can be abbreviated to `psutil.Process().ppid()`.

Answer (score 1):

ppid() is a member method, not variable, of Process, so the above needs to be changed to include the parenthesis.

Source: [psutil documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `psutil` (e.g. because your environment makes installing dependencies and IT request), here's how you can do it manually on Linux.

```py
def get_parent_process_id(pid: int) -> int:
    # Read /proc/<pid>/status and look for the line `PPid:\t120517\n`
    with open(f"/proc/{pid}/status", encoding="ascii") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith("PPid:\t"):
                return int(line[6:])
    raise Exception(f"No PPid line found in /proc/{pid}/status")
```