# python3 : Identify if a python script is executed by bash or powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, git-bash

I have a python script that I run by power shell and git-bash .
Is there any way to identify in python code if the script is executed in power shell or git-bash

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why don't you add a commandline option to choose the behaviour? On Unix machines you can [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539184/after-starting-process-how-to-get-parents-pid-in-the-child) to get information on the parent process but that is not available on Windows.

Comment: The python.exe process is mostly independent of its parent. The only concern would be the console or terminal it uses; is that the issue here? git-bash runs in mintty with the attached console window hidden off screen. mintty uses MSYS named pipes for standard I/O. Many console applications misbehave in this case (e.g. `/c/Windows/System32/timeout.exe 1` fails). The python.exe REPL won't work unless interactive mode is forced with the `-i` option, and any script that uses the console directly will misbehave (e.g. `msvcrt.getch()` or  via opening "conin$" or "conout$").

Answer (score -1):

You can examine the process tree that the current process belongs to.

```
import psutil
import os
this_proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid()) # Get process information for this process
parent_proc = psutil.Process(os.getppid()) # Get process information for the parent process
print("Parent: {}".format(parent_proc.name()))
```