# How to know if a process is launched from cron in python

Tags: python, cron, daemon, python-daemon

We have a use case where we need to distinguish if a process is launched from crontab or if it is a background process in Python ?

Are there any process attributes which can be checked to know if it a cron launched process or it is a background process?

Answer (score 1):

A process launched from `cron` will have `cron` as its parent process.

Of course, in the general case, a process launched from a process which was launched from `cron` will have `cron` as its grandparent; and if the launcher process was a child of `cron` but is now terminated, the child process will be reparented and have `init` (process number 1) as its parent. at which point you can no longer tell if it previously had `cron` as its parent.

None of this is specific to Python, but maybe check [After starting process, how to get parent's PID in the child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539184/after-starting-process-how-to-get-parents-pid-in-the-child) for implementation details.