# In python, how to get the parent PID of specific child PID?

Tags: python

I need to get the parent ID of a specific pid.
I was able to get the pids of a executable process using the `psutil.process_iter()` but I need to know what is the parent of this pids in order to kill the process.

Comment: see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539184/after-starting-process-how-to-get-parents-pid-in-the-child

Answer (score 2):

```
psutil.Process(other_pid).ppid()
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. but when I tried to do ```taskkill /PID <parent id> /T /F``` I'm getting ```Error: The process <parent id> not found.```