# what happens to child process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

What happens to a child process whose parent process is terminated abruptly without waiting? Does the child process die too?

Comment: How to make child process die after parent exits? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits

Answer (score 13):

The child gets [reparented to `init`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

Comment: And, to add to this, that means you need not fear about it walking as a living dead (zombie), because init waitpids.

Answer (score 3):

No, it becomes 'orphaned' (i.e. its parent becomes init - PID 1).