# What happens to the child process, when the parent process calls an exec command

Tags: c, linux, unix

Suppose we have a parent process and if it calls an exec function, after calling a fork to create child process.

Now what happens to the child process: will it act like the original parent process, such that the user won't spot the difference that the parent process got replaced with some other binary ?

I think this question differs from the following question
[what happens to child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678395/what-happens-to-child-process).

```
if ( (pid == fork ()) != 0 )
{
    if (strcmp(cmd,"mypwd")==0)
    {
        execlp (“mypwd”,0);
    }

    ...
    ...

    else if (strcmp(cmd,"myexit")==0)
        exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pid of the parent process will remain the same after the `exec`, so the process hierarchy won't be affected.

The problem with this approach is that the newly replaced parent process generally won't be aware that it has previously spawned a child and will not call `wait` or `waitpid` on it. This will cause the child process to become a zombie when it exits.

Comment: Does it actually need to know about the children, or just have a handler for SIGCHLD?