# Detect death of parent process from `setuid` process

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, setuid

I write C application that calls `fork()` to create child processes. The application runs as root. In the parent process, I use `wait()` for waiting terminated child processes. In child processes, I use `prctl()` with `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` option to detect the death of the parent. It works fine. To reduce the risk of security issues, child processes call `setuid()` to change UID. The problem is: **child processes can not detect the death of the parent one any more.**

I have searched around to find the answer and found some useful links, but it does not help:

- [Detect death of parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193581/detect-death-of-parent-process)
- [Enforcing process hierarchies (`prctl` related)](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2012-August/005988.html) : although this link contains a clear answer, there is no solution.

How to do that correctly?

Comment: Please add a very minimal MCVE so that people can play with it

Comment: do you mean the childs do not receive the signal any more after the setuid call ?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same issue, the kernel resets the `PDEATH` signal on credential change:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/cred.c#L450

This can be verified with the following code and `strace -f`:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (fork() == 0) {
                // This works as expected
                setgid(1000);                                                                                                                                                                                       
                setuid(1000);

                prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);

                // This doesn't work since pdeath_signal will be reset
                // setgid(1000);
                // setuid(1000);

                pause();
        }
        sleep(1);
        kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
        return (0);
}
```