# how to handle os.system sigkill signal inside python?

Tags: python, linux, signals, system

I have a python script where I call a lengthy process from the operating system. After a long while, the process that I call gets terminated by the system by SIGKILL signal.

Is it possible to handle this from inside Python like in a try and catch situation?

What method should I use to solve this issue. It is very important that this process keeps on running as long as possible without any interruptions.

Answer (score 31):

[There is no way to handle `SIGKILL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

If you're looking to handle system shutdown gracefully, you should be handling `SIGTERM` or a startup/shutdown script such as an [upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) or a [init.d script](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html).

Answer (score 16):

The answer is **NO**, you can't handle `SIGKILL` or `kill -9 <pid>` in any process. Only `SIGHUP` can be handled by shutdownhooks but not `SIGKILL` or `-9`. `SIGKILL` is made for aggressive killing the task and only works on kernel level; your process is unaware about the killing.

For keeping long running process you should write a small monitor program which keeps on checking whether the process is alive; if it is found to be killed, just restart the process.

**OR**

Run your process in below loop , hope you got it ;)

```
while true
   do
    /your/script
   sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Note that signal number 15 is normally SIGTERM, and SIGHUP is normally signal number 1.  The `-9` and `-15` notation is for the `kill` command; in the system call interface, the signal numbers are small and positive.

Comment: Note that the script above is a shell script, run it with something like `bash launcher.sh` (assuming you save it as "launcher.sh"). Also, the line `/your/script` assumes your python program is in a file called "script" in the folder "/your", has the executable bit set (see `man chmod`) and starts with the line `#!/bin/bash`. Alternatively replace `/your/script/` with something like `python /your/script.py`. Of course, all that works on linux.