# How to kill ray tasks when the driver is dead

Tags: python, ray

I'm looking into ray to distribute many computation tasks that could run in parallel.
Ray code looks like:

```
ray.init(f"ray://{head_ip}:10001")

@ray.remote
def compute(compute_params):
    # do some long computation
    return some_result

# ==== driver part
ray_res = [compute.remote(cp) for cp in many_computations]
remote_res=ray.get(ray_res)
```

What is the proper way to stop such computation?

Suppose every computation might take a couple of hours, and for some reason, the driver code is killed/stopped/crashed, how is that possible to stop the tasks on the worker machines? Maybe to have some special configuration for workers that will understand that driver is dead...?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [RAY documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html#cancelling-tasks)

> Remote functions can be canceled by calling [ray.cancel](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/package-ref.html#ray-cancel-ref) on the returned Object ref. Remote actor functions can be stopped by killing the actor using the `ray.kill` interface.

In your example it would be something like:

```
ray.init(f"ray://{head_ip}:10001")

@ray.remote
def compute(compute_params):
    # do some long computation
    return some_result
    

# ==== driver part
ray_res = [compute.remote(cp) for cp in many_computations]

for x in ray_res:
    try:
        remote_res=ray.get(x)
    except TaskCancelledError:
        ....
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to kill a task from driver or driver helper . I can call  [ray.cancel.(r) for r in ray_res]. But if my code failed, how can I recreate ray_res to kill long-running tasks?

Comment: Instead of recreating, you should kill them before program exits. You [can't handle system SIGKILL or  SIGSTOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242630/how-to-handle-os-system-sigkill-signal-inside-python) signal, but you can handle almost any other internal exception [including e.g SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)  etc. The simplest way is to surround **all** your code with big `try: ... except (BaseException, Exception):` block.

Comment: in my usecase, the driver is a bash script that is usually killed with kill -9. How can i handle that?

Comment: @Julias you can use kill -15 instead, that sends a `SIGTERM` signal which can be handled in Python. kill -9 sends a `SIGKILL` which cannot be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are automatically killed when the driver exits in Ray. E.g., Try

Start ray using `ray start --head`

```
import ray    
import time
ray.init("auto")

@ray.remote
def f():
    time.sleep(300)

a = f.remote()
# At this point, task should be visible from `ray list tasks` or `ps aux | grep ray::f`
time.sleep(10)
```

and search `ps aux | grep ray::` after the driver exits (all Ray workers are )