# how to get ray task again while the driver submit the task died?

Tags: python, ray

I have a question a bit similar to [How to kill ray tasks when the driver is dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613739/how-to-kill-ray-tasks-when-the-driver-is-dead)

```
ray.init(f"ray://{head_ip}:10001")

@ray.remote
def compute(compute_params):
    # do some long computation
    return some_result
    

# ==== driver part
ray_res = [compute.remote(cp) for cp in many_computations]
```

but I wish to get the task status even if the driver submited tasks are dead.
I know I can do this if I use named Actor,since it can use a name to get actor in another driver connect to the same cluster in same namespace.
but it seems doesn't work for task.
I hope if there is any api that I can use some thing like task_name,or future id to get the task obj again in other driver.
I found I can set name of task,but there is no api I can get it by name or id.

```
compute.options(name="foobar").remote(compute_params)
>> ObjectRef(c8ef45ccd0112571ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000)
```

like

```
ray.get_task_by_name('foobar')
```

or

```
ray.get_task_by_id("c8ef45ccd0112571ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000")
```

---

thx to ray community,they solve my problem now
there is no way to achive this now (202212),you can only use Actor,or use alpha libray
https://discuss.ray.io/t/how-to-get-ray-task-again-while-the-driver-submit-the-task-died/8636

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, currently it is only possible to retrieve the status of a dead actor, and not task. The ability to surface dead task through the state API is planned for next release, in Ray 2.3.

Current state API is in https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-observability/state/state-api.html