# Does linux kill background processes if we close the terminal from which it has started?

Tags: linux, shell, telnet, job-control

I have an embedded system, on which I do `telnet` and then I run an application in background:

```
./app_name &
```

Now if I close my terminal and do `telnet` from other terminal and if I check then I can see this process is still running.

To check this I have written a small program:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    while(1);
}
```

I ran this program in my local linux pc in background and I closed the terminal.

Now, when I checked for this process from other terminal then I found that this process was also killed.

My question is:

- Why undefined behavior for same type of process?
- On which it is dependent?
- Is it dependent on version of Linux?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Who should kill jobs?

Normally, foreground and background jobs are killed by `SIGHUP` sent by kernel or shell in different circumstances.

---

### When does kernel send `SIGHUP`?

*Kernel* sends `SIGHUP` to [*controlling process*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25373501/3169754):

- for real (hardware) terminal: when disconnect is detected in a terminal driver, e.g. on hang-up on modem line;
- for [pseudoterminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) (pty): when last descriptor referencing master side of pty is closed, e.g. when you close terminal window.

*Kernel* sends `SIGHUP` to other process groups:

- to *foreground process group*, when *controlling process* terminates;
- to [*orphaned process group*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31919569/3169754), when it becomes orphaned and it has stopped members.

> Controlling process is the session leader that established the connection to the controlling terminal.

Typically, the controlling process is your shell. So, to sum up:

- kernel sends `SIGHUP` to the shell when real or pseudoterminal is disconnected/closed;
- kernel sends `SIGHUP` to foreground process group when the shell terminates;
- kernel sends `SIGHUP` to orphaned process group if it contains stopped processes.

Note that kernel *does not* send `SIGHUP` to background process group if it contains no stopped processes.

---

### When does `bash` send `SIGHUP`?

*Bash* sends `SIGHUP` to *all* jobs (foreground and background):

- when it receives `SIGHUP`, and it is an interactive shell (and *job control* support is enabled at compile-time);
- when it exits, it is an interactive login shell, and `huponexit` option is set (and *job control* support is enabled at compile-time).

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294799/3169754).

Notes:

- `bash` *does not* send `SIGHUP` to jobs removed from job list using `disown`;
- processes started using `nohup` *ignore* `SIGHUP`.

More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and).

---

### What about other shells?

Usually, shells propagate `SIGHUP`. Generating `SIGHUP` at normal exit is less common.

---

### Telnet or SSH

Under telnet or SSH, the following should happen when connection is closed (e.g. when you close `telnet` window on PC):

1. client is killed;
2. server detects that client connection is closed;
3. server closes master side of pty;
4. kernel detects that master pty is closed and sends `SIGHUP` to `bash`;
5. `bash` receives `SIGHUP`, sends `SIGHUP` to all jobs and terminates;
6. each job receives `SIGHUP` and terminates.

---

### Problem

I can reproduce your issue using `bash` and `telnetd` from `busybox` or `dropbear` SSH server: *sometimes*, background job doesn't receive `SIGHUP` (and doesn't terminate) when client connection is closed.

It seems that a **race condition** occurs when server (`telnetd` or `dropbear`) closes master side of pty:

1. normally, `bash` receives `SIGHUP` and immediately kills background jobs (as expected) and terminates;
2. but sometimes, `bash` detects `EOF` on slave side of pty *before* handling `SIGHUP`.

When `bash` detects `EOF`, it by default terminates immediately without sending `SIGHUP`. And background job remains running!

---

### Solution

It is possible to configure `bash` to send `SIGHUP` on normal exit (including `EOF`) too:

- Ensure that `bash` is started as *login shell*. The `huponexit` [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294799/3169754) only for login shells, AFAIK.

  Login shell is enabled by `-l` option or [*leading hyphen*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128936/why-we-can-not-see-a-single-hyphen-from-0-on-a-login-shell-invoked-with-logi) in `argv[0]`. You can configure `telnetd` to run `/bin/bash -l` or better `/bin/login` which invokes `/bin/sh` in login shell mode.

  E.g.:

  ```
  telnetd -l /bin/login
  ```
- Enable `huponexit` option.

  E.g.:

  ```
  shopt -s huponexit
  ```

  Type this in `bash` session every time or add it to `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`.

---

### Why does the race occur?

`bash` unblocks signals only when it's safe, and blocks them when some code section can't be safely interrupted by a signal handler.

Such *critical sections* invoke *interruption points* from time to time, and if signal is received when a critical section is executed, it's handler is delayed until next interruption point happens or critical section is exited.

You can start digging from [`quit.h`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/quit.h) in the source code.

Thus, it seems that in our case `bash` sometimes receives `SIGHUP` when it's in a critical section. `SIGHUP` handler execution is delayed, and `bash` reads `EOF` and terminates *before* exiting critical section or calling next interruption point.

---

### Reference

- ["Job Control"](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) section in official Glibc manual.
- Chapter 34 "Process Groups, Sessions, and Job Control" of "The Linux Programming Interface" book.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Chirag, I've added a guess to the answer, why the race may occur in `bash`.

Comment: @gavv Thanks. However I did some local testing using `trap`. Bash receives SIGCLD and SIGCONT along with SIGHUP. Why? And why do we need to `Ensure that bash is started as login shell.` ?

Comment: @Amos SIGCLD is usually sent when a child process terminates. One case when SIGCONT is sent is when a process group becomes an orphaned process group. Not sure if it's the case, need more data.

Comment: @Amos "And why do we need to Ensure that bash is started as login shell. ?" -- `huponexit` works for login shells only IIRC http://stackoverflow.com/a/21294799/3169754 "If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt, bash sends a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits." I'll update the answer.

Comment: @gavv Thanks for the clarification. Here is my full test case. `https://paste.wentropy.com/zAcW`

Answer (score 10):

When you close the terminal, shell sends `SIGHUP` to all background processes – and that kills them. This can be suppressed in several ways, most notably:

### nohup

When you run program with `nohup` it catches `SIGHUP` and redirect program output.

```
$ nohup app &
```

### disown

`disown` tells shell not to send `SIGHUP`

```
$ app &
$ disown
```

### Is it dependent on version of linux?

It is dependent on your shell. Above applies at least for **bash**.

Comment: Note than shell usually sends `SIGHUP` only when it receives `SIGHUP` itself (see my answer). The OP's problem, as I understand, is that the shell either does *not* receive or does not propagate `SIGHUP`.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK in both cases the process should be killed. In order to avoid this you have to issue a nohup like the following:

```
> nohup ./my_app &
```

This way your process will continue executing. Probably the telnet part is due to a BUG similar to this one:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=89653

Answer (score 5):

In order completely understand whats happening you need to get into `unix` internals a little bit.

When you are running a command like this

`./app_name &`

The `app_name` is sent to background process group. You can check about `unix` process groups [here](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W99.276/assignment1/signals.html)

When you close `bash` with normal exit it triggers `SIGHUP` hangup signal to all its jobs. Some information on `unix` job control is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29).

In order to keep your app running when you exit `bash` you need to make your app immune to hangup signal with `nohup` utility.

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

And finally this is how you need to do it.

`nohup app_name & 2> /dev/null;`

Comment: Bash doesn't always (ever?) send a SIGHUP to all its jobs with normal exit. It WILL *forward* a SIGHUP from the terminal it's running in. See my answer to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off . Strangely, I have yet to see bash send a SIGHUP even with `shopt -s huponexit`, at least in CentOS7.1. Neither did I see it when bash was run as `/bin/sh`, neither did I see it with `/bin/csh`.

Comment: Does the backgrounded linux process terminate via this signal if I run the background process from a Java ProcessBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

In modern Linux--that is, Linux with systemd--there is an additional reason this might happen which you should be aware of: "linger".

`systemd` kills processes left running from a login shell, even if the process is properly daemonized and protected from HUP. This is the default behavior in modern configurations of systemd.

If you run

```
loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

you can disable this behavior, allowing background processes to keep running. The mechanisms covered by the other answers still apply, however, and you should also protect your process against them.

`enable-linger` is permanent until it is re-disabled. You can check it with

```
ls /var/lib/systemd/linger
```

This may have files, one per username, for users who have enable-linger. Any user listed in the directory has the ability to leave background processes running at logout.