# Bash I/O redirection

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tcl

The main question of my current task is to start process from Tcl environment (using exec cmd.) with I/O redirection to parent process (Tcl) and when parent process unexpectedly stopped I'd like to automatically stop the child process. But there is a caveat: for I/O redirection case child process doesn't stop. The problem is complexed because child process can't be modified.

I've found the next thread [How to make child process die after parent exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits) where solution has been found for C language and without I/O redirection.

So for example, I use the next command in Tcl:

```
exec ping $SERVER_NAME >@ stdout 2>@ stderr
```

This command redirect output of stdout and stderr to the parent process (Tcl).
But I need to run something like that:

```
exec sh -c "set -o monitor; ping $SERVER_NAME >@ stdout 2>@ & read dummy; kill %1"
```

And in the command above output of stdout and stderr goes into "sh" process but I'd like to get it in my parent process. So I have the several question:

1. What mean symbol "@" in the following command (may be you could get a link)?
2. How to make I/O redirection to the Tcl process?
3. How to stop child process (ping in example) if Tcl process unexpectedly stopped?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `>@ stdout` is to send the output of the command to the Tcl process's standard out without collecting it. The meaning of `2>@ stderr` is to send the standard error stream of the command to the Tcl process's standard error without collecting it (if it collected something non-empty, it would lead to an error). Thinking about replicating that in a subprocess invokation, even in bash, makes my head hurt! I suspect that you can't quite do it that way.

It's probably easier to do your processing like this:

```
set pid [exec exec ping $SERVER_NAME >@ stdout 2>@ stderr &]

# and when you want to stop it...
exec kill $pid
```

Doing a more complete job will require using, say, the TclX package's `signal` command.

Comment: Sorry but "set pid [exec exec ping $SERVER_NAME >@ stdout 2>@ stderr &]" doesn't work: Error: couldn't execute "exec": no such file or directory

Comment: @Alexei: try removing one of the `exec`s.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow: Ye, I've tried but in such case pid variable will not be set, because when I stop parent process child continue working and exec wasn't returned, so pid isn't set. I wonder may be some other mistakes in this command?