# QProcess::kill() does not kill children in linux

Tags: c++, qt, process

I use a `QProcess` for a lengthy calculation on a server. It may take only a few seconds or up to several hours and works fine as long as I let it finish on its own. However, I need to have the possibility to kill the process before it finishes which works fine only on my windows machine.

In linux, my `QProcess` is killed and the processing of my data is executed sucessfully, but the child processes spawned by it remain. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```c++
// constructor
server::server(QObject* parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    this->calc_proc = new QProcess(this);
    QObject::connect(this->calc_proc, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(calc_finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));

    ...
}

void server::start_job(){

    QString working_directory = "...";
    QString input_file = "...";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "memory=max" << "batch=no" << input_file;

    this->calc_proc->setWorkingDirectory(working_directory);
    this->calc_proc->start("path_to_external_program", arguments);

    qDebug() << "Calc started with pid: " << this->calc_proc->pid();
}

void server::kill_job(){

    this->calc_proc->terminate();
    //this->calc_proc->kill();
}
```

The behaviour does not seem to differ when using `terminate()` or `kill()`. The child processes are children of my process to my knowledge:

```
Calc started with pid:  26395

ps ax
...
26441 pts/0    S      0:00 time /msc/MSC_Nastran/20131/msc20131/linux64/analysis
26442 pts/0    Rl    16:59 /msc/MSC_Nastran/20131/msc20131/linux64/analysis
...

ps -p 26442 -o ppid=
26441

ps -p 26441 -o ppid=
26395
```

My `QProcess` returns his pid as 26395 which has a child 26441 which has a child 26442. So I'd expect that all of these are killed when I kill mine. As stated they survive. Is there any platform-independent way of killing these as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user4419802 brought me on the correct track. In Linux, killing a process does not kill its children. They are moved up and continue without having a parent anymore.

Generally you'd want to save all `pids` of children when spawning them (and there are multiple answers telling you how to do so) but that was not possible in my case as I am not spawning the children but the external application I call does so without my knowledge. So I came up with the following solution which works good for me:

```
QProcess* main_process = new QProcess(this);
...

// linux: a child is spawned which is not killed with its parent
//        therefore the process id is retrieved and the process killed independently
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
QProcess get_child_a;
QStringList get_child_a_cmd;
get_child_a_cmd << "--ppid" << QString::number(main_process->processId()) << "-o" << "pid" << "--no-heading";
get_child_a.start("ps", get_child_a_cmd);
get_child_a.waitForFinished(5000);
QString child_a_str = get_child_a.readAllStandardOutput();
int child_a = child_a_str.toInt();

QProcess::execute("kill " + QString::number(child_a));
#endif

// windows & linux: kill main process
main_process->kill();
```

In my case, I know that only one child process id is returned so the parsing of the `get_child` process output is a straightforward cast.

Comment: More clean solution is to save child's PID while spawning it, rather than parsing `ps` output. Your code is OS-dependent anyway (`ps --ppid` - GNU only?).

Comment: That would be cleaner, but it is not my code which spawns the children. I just start an external program which, at some point, spawns the children without my knowledge. `ps --ppid` is on the [Unix manpages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) so I'd expect it to work in linux in general....and its not required in my case for windows

Comment: I mean `--ppid` is GNU option, so it's only for GNU/Linux. Neither BSD, nor Solaris etc. will work. So it's quite dirty.

Comment: Ah you're right with that one. Feel free to suggest something more portable as I could not find any solution which is not OS dependant in which neither the parent, nor the child is actually _your own code_

Answer (score 2):

`QProcess::kill()` is just `SIGKILL`. So it's not about Qt, but about Unix process management.

You can read on that issue [How to make child process die after parent exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits)

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @Bowdzone for the initial idea!

As the answer did not 100 percent work for me, because my parent spawns more than one child process, I've adjusted it a bit to this method:

```
void CameraReceiver::stopChildProcesses(qint64 parentProcessId) {
    qDebug() << "stopChildProcesses for parent id:" << parentProcessId;

    QProcess get_childs;
    QStringList get_childs_cmd;
    get_childs_cmd << "--ppid" << QString::number(parentProcessId) << "-o" << "pid" << "--no-heading";
    get_childs.start("ps", get_childs_cmd);
    get_childs.waitForFinished();
    QString childIds(get_childs.readAllStandardOutput());
    childIds.replace('\n', ' ');

    QProcess::execute("kill " + childIds);
}
```

Then I can simply call the following:

```
stopChildProcesses(parentProcess.processId());
```

Comment: Perfect for me. As a possible upgrade, it may be useful to make it recursive to kill grandchildren etc. Anyway, Thanks a lot Manuel =)