# Can a process tell whether it was started directly by init?

Tags: unix

On a Unix system, there are two circumstances where [`getppid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getppid) will return 1: either the calling process' original parent has exited, or it was directly started by `init`. Sometimes one might wish to behave differently depending on which of the two it is; for example, the program in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496478/prctlpr-set-pdeathsig-race-condition) wants to exit when its parent does, and one way to detect that is to notice that the value returned by `getppid` is now 1, but `init` never exits, so if the program was directly started by `init` it should not exit.  You can't tell by calling `getppid` at the very beginning of `main`, because your parent might have exited before you ever get a chance to run — if it did the double-fork trick to dissociate from a shell, for instance.

In days of yore, being directly started by `init` was only a realistic possibility for a tiny handful of processes, `/etc/rc` and maybe some `getty`s, but nowadays we have containers and much more powerful "system manager" programs run as `init`, so it's much more likely to come up.

So the question is, is there any 100% reliable way for a program to tell whether its *original* parent was `init`?  OS-specific answers are OK, I'm almost certain there's no way to do it within POSIX.

Comment: The process run time should be an indicator of if `init` at the system start-up started it, I suppose?

Comment: No way, there is no paternity history defined in POSIX systems.