# how to write java program get pid

Tags: java, process, pid

how to write java program get pid?

Comment: This is far too vague. Get the pid of what?

Comment: Make your question more specific. Otherwise - close++;

Comment: duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138097/how-do-i-find-my-pid-in-java-or-jruby-on-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/process-id-in-java ?

Answer (score 5):

[How a Java Application Can Discover its Process ID (PID)](http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html)

Not very straightforward, but apparently there is no "official" way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using JMX, but beware. The below is not an officially supported mechanism and could change. However, I've used this in the past and it works fine.

```
RuntimeMXBean rmxb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
System.err.println("pid: " + rmxb.getName());
```

will print {pid}@hostname

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is something Java supplies. For a start, it breaks the platform-independent nature. I can see two ways to approach it, both assuming you're running under a UNIX-type system.

- provide a JNI which will call `getpid()` and return it.
- use system or one of the Runtime methods to run an external program which will call `getppid()` to get the PID of its parent (i.e., Java), or worse case, walk up the process tree until you find Java itself.