# How to suspend/resume a process created by ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, process

`ProcessBuilder.start()` returns a `Process` object through which I can access the 3 streams (STDIN, STDERR, STDOUT) of the new process.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to access the process id of the created process through the Process interface. Is there a way to access the process id?

Beyond this, I wished to do something like calling `SuspendProcess()` and `ResumeProcess()` [Win32 APIs]

Is there a way to do these things in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. If you are in control of the started process you could have it read its stdin for stop/start messages, and write them from the starting Java code via Process.getOutputStream().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you.
[How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35842/603314)