# How can I find out the pid of a running equinox instance, is there a pid file?

Tags: java, linux, process, osgi, equinox

How can I find out the pid of a running equinox instance, is there a pid file somewhere or is it configurable where it places a pid file?

**UPDATE**: to make it clear, I have a bunch of instances running, and they are configured roughly the same, so any user only looking for equinox will not know which instance is which

Answer (score 3):

Just execute the following command from CLI:

```
ps aux | grep equinox
```

[EDIT]
Does equinox bind to some port?
If so, for multiple instances you can recognize the one you are interested in basis on port to which it is bound:

```
sudo netstat -npa |grep equinox
```

Comment: This doesn't help me because there are several instances running, and a user doesn't see at a glance, which instance is which.

Comment: it is a good idea, but I'd rather have a pid file to which I can point the user.

Comment: So how do you start multiple instances on the same machine? If you use different start scripts, you should use 'ps aux' because it contains whole name of command that was executed. If you use the same script, and magically equinox detects to which port bind the new instance, you should use 'netstat'. I do not see any other option to do so.

Comment: It is not so much that I for myself can't find out which instance is which, it is a matter that the actual administrator knows at once which instance he has to kill in case it is not working anymore. For other programs we run, we have a pid file for each one, only not for equinox. So if there is a way to tell equinox to put its/a pid file in the same directory I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

No, Equinox does not create a PID file or report its PID.

You could write a bundle that does this for you, but be aware that there is no standard way for a Java program to retrieve its PID (because some target operating systems don't even have the concept of "PID"). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/process-id-in-java) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pidof equinox
```

From the man page:

PIDOF(8)              Linux System Administrator's Manual             PIDOF(8)

NAME
       pidof -- find the process ID of a running program.

SYNOPSIS
       pidof [-s] [-c] [-x] [-o omitpid] [-o omitpid..]  program [program..]

DESCRIPTION
       Pidof  finds  the  process id's (pids) of the named programs. It prints
       those id's on the standard output. This program is on some systems used
       in  run-level change scripts, especially when the system has a System-V
       like  rc  structure.  In  that  case  these  scripts  are  located   in
       /etc/rc?.d,  where  ?  is the runlevel. If the system has a start-stop-
       daemon (8) program that should be used instead.

OPTIONS

-s     Single shot - this instructs the program to only return one pid.

-c     Only return process ids that are  running  with  the  same  root
              directory.   This  option is ignored for non-root users, as they
              will be unable to check the current root directory of  processes
              they do not own.

-x     Scripts  too  -  this  causes the program to also return process
              id's of shells running the named scripts.

-o omitpid
              Tells pidof to omit processes with that process id. The  special
              pid  %PPID  can  be used to name the parent process of the pidof
              program, in other words the calling shell or shell script.

EXIT STATUS

0      At least one program was found with the requested name.

1      No program was found with the requested name.

Comment: this doesn't help me, 1.) pidof is not installed, 2.) I don't know which process is which.