# What is the right command line to get cpu usage for certain process in java

Tags: java, command-line, process, cpu

Given a process ID, what is the right command to get the current cpu usage from the process, in Java.

The command typeperf "\Memory\Available bytes" "\processor(_total)\% processor time" is not for a specific process, and any 3rd party utility is not a option, ProcDump alike. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Try http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home

Otherwise look at [How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/process-id-in-java)