# Get the CPU usage of program in Java

Tags: java, cpu

I am creating a program in java which runs another program in java.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java process1");
```

I want to get the CPU usage of this process.

Comment: Possible duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359245/what-is-the-right-command-line-to-get-cpu-usage-for-certain-process-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I didn't find the answer that I need, from this link

Comment: If you're running linux create a script that does `time java process1`, run that from your parent and parse the output from the `time` command in your parent.