# How do I obtain the PID of a spawned java process

Tags: java, process, pid, spawn

I am writing several java programs and will need to kill off/clean up in a seperate JVM after I am done with whatever I wanted to do. For this, I will need to get the PID of the java process which I am creating.

Comment: This [link](http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html) may help you.

Comment: Appears to be a question very similar to [Process ID in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/process-id-in-java)

Comment: Ken a little bit more information may be helpful. It sounds like you are wanting to launch Java program A, program B, and program C. Then have Java program D kill the processes of A,B, and C. Are you launching A,B, and C from program D? Is there a reason A,B, and D can't tidy up after themselves?

Comment: If you don't tell us *how* you are creating these processes, we can't help you.

Comment: hey yes, basically i am using jvm A to spawn a seperate process of jvm B and jvm A would have ended. after doing some work, I will need jvm C to kill off jvm B

Comment: I tried using java native but to no avail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jps -l` works both on Windows and Unix. You can invoke this command from your java program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. Sample output of `jps -l` is as follows

```
9412 foo.bar.ClassName
9300 sun.tools.jps.Jps
```

You might need to parse this and then check for the fully qualified name and then get the pid from the corresponding line.

```
private static void executeJps() throws IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jps -l");
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String [] javaProcess = line.split(" ");
        if (javaProcess.length > 1 && javaProcess[1].endsWith("ClassName")) {
            System.out.println("pid => " + javaProcess[0]);
            System.out.println("Fully Qualified Class Name => " + 
                                           javaProcess[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works on Win7 64 bits and JDK 1.8 :D I just changed: if (javaProcess.length > 1 && javaProcess[1].contains("myJarName"))

Answer (score 0):

you can try execute command

`pidof <program name>`

for you to find the pid of your program.

It is in Linux env.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Java 9 is going to expose some system-agnostic methods such as:

```
System.out.println("Your pid is " + Process.getCurrentPid());
```