# How to get By Process, Runtime and ProcessId Java

Tags: java, process, runtime, pid

How to get Runtime and PID with a process? In my application I start the Process with ProcessBuilder like this:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(rgumentsList).toArray(new String[argumentsList.size()]));
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.directory(getInstanceMainDir());
instanceProcess = processBuilder.start();
```

How do I get `instanceProcess`'s Runtime and PID? I need Runtime to check the memory used by this app and PID to check used CPU.

Comment: It's okay! Here on Stack Overflow, your English can be as terrible as you want and as long as it's comprehensible, [somebody will edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2655568) to make it better :)

Comment: i saw this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834270/how-do-i-obtain-the-pid-of-a-spawned-java-process but how to get Runtime and pid when i know only start Command, i don't know app name etc.