# Obtaining the thread ID for Java threads in Linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, pid

I have a Java application where some threads are created (via `new Thread()`). Using `ps` I can see they have different thread IDs (LWP column) and I would like to obtain those IDs from within the Java application.

In most of the posts related to this topic that I have found (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/process-id-in-java)), the solution is to use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()`.

Using that method, however, gives me the PID of the main thread (even if I call it from one of the threads), so it is not really solving my problem.

Is there any way to obtain the thread ID for every single `Thread` created by an application?

Would it be possible to use JNI to accomplish it? If somehow I could interface to a C function where I could call `syscall(__NR_gettid)`, that could solve my problem. I really do not care about portability, so I am totally okay with a solution that would only work for a Linux machine.

**UPDATE:** I have actually solved my problem by using JNI. Details are explained in my answer. Thank you all for your suggestions/comments.

Comment: Java Thread may not correspond to an actual thread on the OS.

Comment: @nhahtdh I am not 100% sure how Java threads map to Linux threads, but at least in my system, they have a given thread ID as a pthread would have. As I said, I am not really looking for a portable solution.

Comment: @betabandido: So, have you tried to implement that JNI function? Or are we supposed to do that for you?

Comment: @NiklasB. I was not asking for that. Since I am not really used to write Java code anymore, and I have never touched JNI, I just wanted to know if it is a viable option. If the answer is yes, I will definitely look at it myself.

Comment: @betabandido: You should definitely try it out. I don't see why that should not work.

Comment: Something I found while searching for a definitive answer: http://www.coderanch.com/t/561229/threads/java/relationship-between-java-thread-native

Comment: @NiklasB. Okay, I will implement it and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @NiklasB. Done :) Using JNI was simpler than what I expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end, I found the JNI way to be the best one to solve my problem. As a reference, I post the code and build instructions for it (based on the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#Examples) at Wikipedia):

Java class responsible to interface to the C code (`GetThreadID.java`):

```
public class GetThreadID {
    public static native int get_tid();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("GetThreadID");
    }
}
```

C file responsible to obtain the thread ID (`GetThread.c`):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include "GetThreadID.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_GetThreadID_get_1tid(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jint tid = syscall(__NR_gettid);
    return tid;
}
```

An example of how to use `GetThreadID` class:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tid = GetThreadID.get_tid();
        System.out.println("TID=" + tid);
    }
}
```

And finally, the build instructions (`javah` automatically generates `GetThreadID.h`):

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
javac GetThreadID.java
javah GetThreadID

gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -fPIC -shared GetThreadID.c -o libGetThreadID.so
javac Main.java
java Main
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the follow-up. I suspected it wouldn't be too much work :) I think you should accept your own answer here, as it's definitely the best answer.

Comment: I think the gcc instruction here should be gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux -fPIC -shared GetThread.c -o libGetThreadID.so now a days :D!

Comment: Apparently this won't work if you will omit JAVA_HOME part. Specially if you have set the JAVA_HOME already. But if you follow the instructions plus my modifications this works.

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](http://javadrama.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/why-is-java-eating-my-cpu.html) provides a method of mapping from java thread ids to LWP ids.

The gist of it seems to be that the NLWP id maps to the java thread id.

Comment: I think that blog post talks about *manually* mapping the threads. OP wants to do it automatically from within Java

Comment: @NiklasB: I know. My point was that it probably can be done automatically if the OP is willing to map the thread ids to NLWP id instead of LWP id.

Comment: @SeanReilly This definitely looks promising. As you are saying, it could be automated. I will explore this way, as well as the JNI (which would be more direct, but I do not know yet whether it will work). Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post link only answers.

Comment: @gustavohenke: Thanks for the very timely comment. ;-)