# Matching Java thread-ID to native Linux PID

Tags: java, linux, performance

I need to match java thread ids to its native linux pids.
I can't use `kill -3 <PID>`  because I don't own to output stream or `jstack <PID>` because I'm running with JRE and not JDK.

Tried `pstack` from the linux side, and JVM Management classes from java side - without any success.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224394/obtaining-the-thread-id-for-java-threads-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

The `Thread` id is not related to the underlying OS thread id. It is a value assigned to that `Thread` instance from a `static` counter.

```
/* For generating thread ID */
private static long threadSeqNumber;

private static synchronized long nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}
```

You will need to use some `native` call to get the actual value, possibly with what's proposed in [Juned's link in the comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252149/matching-java-thread-id-to-native-linux-pid/19252224#comment28499252_19252149)