# How get Java Virtual Machine Threads and stop them?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, jvm

I am having a problem with my application since some of threads I create become stuck , I have a way to find out what are they , I am trying to write a process to stop these threads [ kill them ] from outside my application since it becomes unresponsive when the stuck threads count increases over time [ I tried to fix the root cause but seems that it sometimes happens because of database aquire connection lock ]

Is there any way to access the JVM from outside I tried `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine` but it didn't work is there any other way

Regards,

Comment: This sound like quite dirty workaround. I would suggest implementing some mechanism to kill (e.x. timeout) the thread inside the process that starts it.

Comment: I must support Lemonov's comment, you should fix you application rather than cleaning up it's crap with an extra garbage collector. Very bad practice. Find the root of your freezing threads, fix it, enjoy.

Comment: well , I know and as I said I can't control the thread behavior , and at what step in the process the thread comes stuck is not clear and not fixed @Lemonov

Comment: Se you can't modify source of the problematic application?@AhMaDAbUIeSa

Comment: Anyway it seems to be possible but it varies depending on OS. Here related topic (Windows): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441878/attach-to-already-running-jvm.

Comment: The OS that I am using is Linux redhat, and if I can do that using java would be better [ the described solution is C++ ]  @Lemonov

Comment: You can try killing/stopping the thread by simply getting pid of thread and sending proper signal to it but i can not guarantee that it would not kill/stop also the parent pid. You can achieve even from linux shell.

Comment: @Lemonov , what I have as a process is the main application java pid [ I can't get the thread id ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148318/discussion-between-lemonov-and-ahmad-abuiesa).

Comment: `jstack` will list all Java threads with stack traces and with the corresponding native thread id (`nid`), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550955/3448419)

Comment: @Lemonov ok when I get the output how can I use the output to stop or send a signal to that process to quit or stop [ here talking about a thread ]

Comment: @apangin , and what can I do with nid [ can I use kill or a process to abort the thread ]

Comment: You cannot kill a single thread in Linux. Even if you could, this would not help, since the resources/locks acuired by the thread would not be released. There must another way to solve your problem, e.g. by setting connection timeout or something.

Comment: This sounds like a bad bodge to me:(  As others have suggested - fix the root cause.

Comment: @apangin tried that [setting the timeout ] , but once the thread is stuck no way to handle that according to the environment

Comment: I never tried it but take a look into JMX http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

VisualVM also uses the JMX to monitor other JVM's and do monitoring of local and remote machines (you can access and capture thread information and thread dump too)

Comment: @swanandingawale I am trying to terminate the thread that I already know all the information regarding the threads , tried the JMX [like] on my environment setup , and found nothing to help my case