# Getting Started java Thread LWP

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I'm using the **java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService** library to implement multithreading and it works good, Now i need to store every started thread LWP: **An LWP is the unit of a basic execution context**. (which i get using the following command line )

```
amira@amira:~/workspace/XXX/XXX/Generator$ ps -lf -L
F S UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 R amira     3702  8646  3702  0    1  80   0 -  1229 -      09:46 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -lf -L
0 S amira     8646 26393  8646  0    1  80   0 -  2884 wait   Dec23 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

in a database because we will need it to make statistics and solve bugs. So how to retrieve it in my code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Java intends to abstract this away from you.

Comment: "An LWP is the unit of a basic execution context" <-- nosir. This is OS dependent. With Linux, for instance, the most basic execution context is a product of `clone(2)`. The only differences between the parent and the child is what the parent chooses what the child will share with it. As it happens, all of `fork()`, `vfork()` and `pthread_create()` use `clone()` behind the scenes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining the thread ID for Java threads in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224394/obtaining-the-thread-id-for-java-threads-in-linux)