# Java - get PID of external process by command line in Windows 7

Tags: java, command-line, pid

I have Windows 7 32 bit with Java:

How do I get the PID of a process by command line in Windows 7?

I want to kill an application which I only can truly identify by the command line which ran it.  We have several Java applications running on that machine. I need to stop specific ones.

To be exact: I need to find tomcat which is run by `catalina.bat`.  What do you think is the best way to do this?

I know of tasklist, but it does not seem to be able to query the command line which started the process.  Finding `java.exe` does not help me.  I tried searching for something useful like pgrep/pkill for Windows, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something. The solution working for me is called wmic (Windows Management Instrumentation Commandline). This nice tool comes built-in to Windows 7 Pro (mine) and possibly other Windows versions. It provides a quite large variety of actions like listing all the running tasks with every details you can imagine (like their corresponding command line), various hardware info, etc. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `jps -lv` command to determine java process by it's command line options. jps is utility that included in many up-to-date JDKs.

Comment: Great idea. Didn't know jps. This will work for a while. Nevertheless I'm still interested if there's a system-wide solution. (I already accepted that there won't be any system-independent solution.)

Answer (score 3):

Try in a command prompt:

```
sc queryex type= service state= all | find "APP"
```

Where APP is the name of the program. This command will return all services that match that.

Then you can run `SC QUERYEX APP` and it will return the state and PID number.

Once you have the PID:

```
TASKKILL /f /pid ###
```

Where ### is the actual PID

Answer (score 3):

**Java, get the PID of the current running process in Windows**

This should work on `Linux`, `OSX`, `Windows`, and HotSpot JVM's.

```
import sun.management.VMManagement;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public static int getCurrentPID() {
    try{
        java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = 
            java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
        jvm.setAccessible(true);
        sun.management.VMManagement mgmt = 
           (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
        java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method = 
            mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
        pid_method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed at getting the process ID");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
System.out.println("PID: " + getCurrentPID());
```

For me it prints the processID: `PID: 5728`

Sources:

[How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id)

http://boxysystems.com/index.php/java-tip-find-process-id-of-running-java-process/

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to kill a specific tomcat from a java application why not coding a simple servlet running inside each tomcat that will responde to a get request with a string that will identify it. Then use another servlet to execute something like:

```
System.exit(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice idea. That also came to my mind just after I posted this question here, but does not solve my issues in the long run. It should work for now but in the future I will need to shutdown other Java applications as well.