# Collecting jvm details like deadlock before shut-down of server

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying something like this.I have a application server I want to know is there a way to collect the jvm details like thread deadlock before graceful shutdown.I  can use 
`ShutDownHook` but in shut down hook how to collect  the jvm details like deadlock etc.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a Java thread dump without restarting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842344/generate-a-java-thread-dump-without-restarting)

Comment: But deadlock is not a piece of information, it is a runtime state. The information you would be able to get is the thread dumps, and from that you might reason that there is a deadlock.

Comment: @Gimby [`ThreadMXBean#findDeadlockedThreads`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#findDeadlockedThreads%28%29) can detect deadlocks.

Comment: Magic. I stand corrected.

Comment: I am trying to do programmatically not using any tool!May be  assylias is giving pointer

Comment: I'd still say use jstack.  You can do a Runtime.exec() to launch it from your ShutdownHook.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be executed from inside java?  Externally you can use jstack.

Answer (score 1):

jstack is platform dependent and it is not available on all platforms. Therefore jstack may not be useful under all situations.

It is not possible to create full JVM thread dump from within JVM. You may call  JVM_dumpAllStacks function on JVM DLL to create thread dump. It depends on whether that route is acceptable for you because it involves JNI and some native coding. Look at [Open JDK Bug list](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6362129) for some more information and knowing efforts to get this functionality from java management APIs. Other JVMs may also follow this route in future. In that case you will be able to invoke JVM thread dump through management API.

At this time only option you may have (when you don't want to take JNI route) is creating thread dumps using good old methods like this: [Creating a Thread Dump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs45/techsupport/threaddump.html)