# Find unix command PID from Java

Tags: java, unix, process, pid

It is very easy to get the PID of previous process in unix-

```
echo $!
```

But, suppose I **execute a unix command via Java**-

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myScript.sh");
```

Now, how do I now get the **PID** of "myScript.sh" **also through Java** ??

e.g.-
In Unix, we would do-
1. Execute `myScript.sh`
2. Execute `ps -ef | grep -i "myScript.sh" | grep -v grep`

Output would be like-

```
     UID   PID  PPID   C    STIME TTY         TIME CMD
userprod 11764 28386   0 05:57:45 pts/3       0:01 myScript.sh
```

What I require **through Java** is the PID, which in this case is "11764".

p.s.- the script will also be executed from Java, not from shell.

Comment: Related: [How can a Java program get it's own process ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35842/1288)

Comment: @dogbane Thanks, that is what I was looking for, reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this works;

```
that process(Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myScript.sh"))
```

is a java.lang.UNIXProcess and it has a field pid; use reflection to get the value

Comment: Edited to format your code.